# Get an array of custom taxonomy with posts inside each items

Tags: taxonomy

I want to obtain an array like that for a custom taxonomy (cat-formation) and custom post types (formation) inside each terms  :

```
custom_taxonomy_term_1
    custom_post_type_post_1 (taxonomized with term_1)
    custom_post_type_post_2 (taxonomized with term_1)
    custom_post_type_post_3 (taxonomized with term_1)
custom_taxonomy_term_2
    custom_post_type_post_4 (taxonomized with term_2)
    custom_post_type_post_5 (taxonomized with term_2)
custom_taxonomy_term_3
    custom_post_type_post_6 (taxonomized with term_3)
    custom_post_type_post_7 (taxonomized with term_3)
    custom_post_type_post_8 (taxonomized with term_3)
...
```

Is there a way to get this ?
Thank you !

Comment: custom_post_type_1 and all are the post belong to a particular custom post type?? correct?

Comment: I've a custom post type with a custom taxonomy. I just want to obtain an array as like I said above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$terms = get_terms( 'custom_taxonomy', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args = [
        'post_type'   => 'custom_post_type', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query'   => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $term->term_id,
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    $result[ $term->term_id ] = $posts->posts;

}
```

In result you will have associative array with

$result[ TERMID_1 ] = ARRAY( POST_OBJECT_OF_TERMID_1 );

$result[ TERMID_2 ] = ARRAY( POST_OBJECT_OF_TERMID_2 );

$result[ TERMID_3 ] = ARRAY( POST_OBJECT_OF_TERMID_3 );